# Command line tool/script to script out all Oracle 10g packages/procedures/functions etc.?

Tags: oracle, scripting, oracle10g, ddl

I'd like to be able to automatically save the DDL scripts from my development schema on a regular basis.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DDL is code, you should use source control to archive any code.

See also those questions ([among others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql]+source+control)) on SO for some example:

- [Should you store your SQL Stored Procedures in Source Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567405/should-you-store-your-sql-stored-procedures-in-source-control)
- [Source Control and stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468703/source-control-and-stored-procedures)
- [Maintaining stored procedures in source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024584/maintaining-stored-procedures-in-source-control)

Comment: I think Cade is asking about how to export the DDL in the first place rather than how to secure it afterwards.

Comment: @Jonners: there are many tools that would provide the initial export -- Oracle SQL Developer for example is free and comes with this feature. Afterwards I stand by my answer: you don't need to export *on a regular basis* your DDL scripts because you already have them in your source control repository.

Comment: This isn't a question about source control.  While I agree that all changes to a database and all object creation scripts should be in source control, this question is not about that.  I have a schema which gets changed through a variety of methods and I need to take snapshots of it as scripts so I can look at them without taking full backups.

Comment: @Cade Roux: In that case I would use `exp` with `rows=N`. This will export all DDL without data (and can be used in scripts).

Comment: exp works better for this than expdp, since I don't have easy access to the server

Answer (score 1):

You can use the datapump to generate DDL statements.

`expdp schemaname/password reuse_dumpfiles=y include=directory full=y content='METADATA_ONLY' directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=ddl_scripts.dmp`